# Lucas' theorem Consequence

Tags: number-theory, binomial-coefficients, modular-arithmetic

[Lucas' theorem consequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27_theorem#Consequence)

$$\binom {m}{n}=\ \prod_{i=0}^k\;\ \binom {m_i}{n_i} \pmod{p},$$
$$m=m_k\;p^k+m_{k-1}\;p^{k-1}+\cdots +m_1\; p+m_0,$$ 
$$n=n_k\;p^k+n_{k-1}\;p^{k-1}+\cdots +n_1\;p+n_0$$

Lucas' theorem states that a binomial coefficient $C(m,n)$ is divisible by a prime $p$ if and only if at least one of the base $p$ digits of $n$ is greater than the corresponding digit of $m$.

Assuming $n_i$ is greater than $m_i$, then what is $C(m_i,n_i)$?

Can someone explain this to me? Thank you. I can't post images.

Comment: The binomial coefficient is zero if its lower index is bigger than its upper index.

Comment: Your images of formulas are unreadable to me. Cannot you put them here using this site Latex engine?

Answer (score 0):

> Lucas' theorem states that a binomial coefficient $C(m,n)$ is divisible
>   by a prime $p$ if and only if at least one of the base $p$ digits of $n$ is
>   greater than the corresponding digit of $m$.

Lucas theorem uses the convention that ${}^mC_n$ is zero when $m < n$, which is what is considered for binomial coefficients.

For Ex : ${}^8c_3 = 56$ is divisible by $2$ ,as $3 = 0011(\text{base }2)$ has at least one of the binary digit greater than the corresponding binary digits in $8 = 1000(\text{base }2)$.